# Ranking sums from first to third c#

Tags: c#

I want to rank the number i added up from first to third but i cant think of a way to rank it properly since when there is a duplicate it will only show the number once and continues to the second highest

im new to the language and it would be great for someone to help me on this

Edit: Sorry i think there is a misunderstanding here my sums are in an array that is connected to the names in another array and im trying to sort it out with the same index value

Edit 2: Also i am stuck at c# 7.3 so i cant use some of the new codes

```
int first = Int32.MinValue;
            int fs, nd, thr;
            int temp = 0;
            for (fs = 0; fs < hounds; fs++)
            {
                if (score_SUM[fs] > first)
                {
                    first = score_SUM[fs];
                    temp = fs;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "First:{1} {0}", first, houndname[temp]);

            int second = Int32.MinValue;
            for (nd = 0; nd < hounds; nd++)
            {

                if (score_SUM[nd] > second && score_SUM[nd] < first)
                {
                    second = score_SUM[nd];
                    temp = nd;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Second:{1} {0}", second, houndname[temp]);

            int third = Int32.MinValue;
            for (thr = 0; thr < hounds; thr++)
            {

                if (score_SUM[thr] > third && score_SUM[thr] < second)
                {
                    third = score_SUM[thr];
                    temp = thr;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Third:{1} {0}", third, houndname[temp]);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

example

10 , 5 , 10 , 6, 1

The output will be like

10
6
5

But I expected

10
10
6

but i cant find a way to write a block a code for that

Comment: It sounds like you're drastically over-engineering this.  If you have an list of integers, you can *sort* that list (descending in this case) and just display the first three elements of the sorted list.

Comment: Yes i have also thought of that but because i need to put the names and sum together i cant think of anything else that could do it P.S the names and sums are all arrays that are interconnected

Comment: If by "arrays that are interconnected" you mean *separate* arrays of values which you need to manually keep synchronized then what you want is an array of meaningful objects, not separate arrays of values.

Comment: Yes that is what i want, but i dont think its manual for me kind of automatica tbh

Answer (score 2):

You're *drastically* over-engineering this.

If what you have is an array (or list/collection of some kind) of values then you can simply *sort* that array (descending in this case) and display the first three values.

For example, consider this list of values:

```
var hounds = new List<int> { 10, 5, 10, 6, 1 };
```

Then you can *sort* that list:

```
hounds = hounds.OrderByDescending(h => h).ToList();
```

And, either in a loop or by directly referencing the first three (if you know there will always be at least three), output them.  For example:

```
Console.WriteLine("First:{0}", hounds[0]);
Console.WriteLine("Second:{0}", hounds[1]);
Console.WriteLine("Third:{0}", hounds[2]);
```

---

Regarding your edit...

> my sums are in an array that is connected to the names in another array and im trying to sort it out with the same index value

You're doing it wrong.

Instead of trying to manually keep multiple arrays of values synchronized, maintain *one* array of *meaningful objects*.  For example, consider how you define a "hound":

```
public class Hound
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Create your list of *hounds*, not multiple lists of disconnected and unrelated values that you need to manually remember and keep synchronized.  For example:

```
var hounds = new List<Hound>
{
    new Hound { Value = 10, Name = "Fido" },
    new Hound { Value = 5, Name = "Barney" },
    new Hound { Value = 10, Name = "Jake" },
    new Hound { Value = 6, Name = "Woof" },
    new Hound { Value = 1, Name = "Dog" }
};
```

The rest of the process is the same.  Sort the list:

```
hounds = hounds.OrderByDescending(h => h.Value);
```

And output the data:

```
Console.WriteLine("First:{1} {0}", hounds[0].Value, hounds[0].Name);
Console.WriteLine("Second:{1} {0}", hounds[1].Value, hounds[1].Name);
Console.WriteLine("Third:{1} {0}", hounds[2].Value, hounds[2].Name);
```

---

Overall, the main point here is that you don't need a ton of convoluted logic just to get the top 3 values in a list.  Sorting is a common and well-established operation.  All you need is the right data structure to be sorted.

Or, as usual, someone else has already said it better before...

> "Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other way around."
> Eric S. Raymond, The Cathedral & the Bazaar

Comment: I think im asking too much but are you able to check a part of my code, i cant put it all up since it is a part of uni project but thanks tho i think i can work around with this :) there are some codes that i havent learnt since this is my first month learning the language and starting to progran

Comment: @AlanDong: If what you're asking for is personal one-on-one tutoring services then, yes, what you're asking is too much for Stack Overflow.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.  The scope of answers provided is limited to the scope of the question asked.  In this case that scope is how to reliably display the "top 3" values in a collection of values.

Comment: Right i think i didnt explain it correctly but i need to input my names and values in the prompt i think what you have written is that i have already manually entered the values in the code beforehand. But thanks tho the code that you just put up is kinda new to me and ill try and learn it edit: i am stuck at c# 7.3 so i cant use the new code

Comment: @AlanDong: The code shown in the question, and the problem described in the question, have nothing to do with reading input from the user.  And there's nothing stopping you from reading input from the user.  The hard-coded values in the answer are just for demonstration purposes.  Understand that these answers are meant for you to learn concepts.  These are ***not*** meant for you to simply copy/paste the code given to you and submit it as your own without understanding what it does.

Comment: Ah yes i understand its just that i cant use some of the codes you used in here since im handicapped by the version that im only allowed to use but thanks tho this helps alot for me in the future

Comment: @AlanDong: None of the code in this answer is using any "new" features of C#.  (Not since the past 15 years at least.)  Have you actually tried anything?  Have you encountered an actual problem?  Sorry, but it seems that you're just making up an ongoing series of excuses until someone gives you a solution that you can copy/paste into your homework.  That's unlikely to happen here.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Side note: `hounds.Sort((left, right) => right.CompareTo(left));` sorts `hounds` in place without unwanted overhead as in `hounds = hounds.OrderByDescending(h => h).ToList();` version

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question?

```
List<int> list = new() { 10, 5, 10, 6, 1 };

list.Sort((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x));
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{  
Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
}
```

If you only want the three highest values you can also do this:

```
List<int> list = new() { 10, 5, 10, 6, 1 };
IEnumerable<int> highestValues = list.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(3);
foreach (int value in highestValues)
{
Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but im not that deep into c# yet so i dont know what the code does but what i want is that when ranking the values with duplicates the value needs to be first to third even if there is duplicate like what i wrote 

10 , 5 , 10 , 6, 1

correct 10 10 6
wrong 10 6 5

P.S sorry for broken english

Comment: Have you already tried running my code? When you run them they will both write `10, 10, 6` to the console.

Comment: sorry i cant since i am not allowed to use c# 9.0 i am stuck at 7.3

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `<` symbols to `<=` symbols.  So your checks for the second and third ranks would look something like this:

```
// check for second
if (score_SUM[nd] > second && score_SUM[nd] <= first)
...

// check for third
if (score_SUM[thr] > third && score_SUM[thr] <= second)
...
```

Comment: Yea i tried that but it actually duplicates the first highest for the second and third

Comment: ah makes sense. You could remove the highest value from the list as you find it (you'd have to change the length of the for loops).